# What's the technique to let user paint on a view?

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

What are the best practices under iOS to let user paint in interactive mode a rectangle, or a segment or other simple shape? Say I catch when user presses first time, then when moving the finger what shall I do? Shall I catch the current coordinate, set some internal point and call setNeedsDisplay for the view and paint the line between those 2 points?

What if I want to paint on a surface that has already bunch of shapes in there? Wouldn't it take too much time to go over them all and repaint again?

Under Windows I was using the XOR operation to paint only what's needed when user moved the mouse, what are the techniques in iOS?
Any articles are much appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void) drawSquareFrom:(CGPoint)from to:(CGPoint)to {
    CGContextRef context = [self offscreenContext];
    CGRect draw , full = [self offscreenContextBounds];

    draw.origin = from;
    draw.size.width = to.x - from.x;
    draw.size.height = to.y - from.y;
    draw = CGRectStandardize( draw );

    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    CGContextClearRect( context , full );
    CGContextFillRect( context , draw );
    CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth( context , draw , 10 );
    [_imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(CGContextRef) offscreenContext {
    if ( nil == myContext ) {
        size_t width = 400;
        size_t height = 300;
        CFMutableDataRef data = CFDataCreateMutable( NULL , width * height * 4 ); // 4 is bytes per pixel
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData( data );
        CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate( width , height , ... , provider , ... );
        CGBitmapContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate( CFDataGetMutableBytePtr( data ) , width , height , ... );
        CFRelease( data ); // retained by provider I think
        CGDataProviderRelease( provider ); // retained by image

        myImage = image;
        myContext = context;
        myContextFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
        myContextFrame.size.width = width;
        myContextFrame.size.height = height;
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
    }

    return myContext;
}
-(CGRect) offscreenContextBounds {
    return myContextFrame;
}
```

Hope it'll help

Comment: I know how paint using Quartz, question was how to let user paint by using his finger. Like a small Visio type of application :)

Comment: Maybe this link will help you:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D

Comment: Alex, please read my question carefully, and check your comment, where do you see the interaction with user using touch events. As I told, I know very well how to paint using Quartz, question is what are the usual techniques to let user paint some kind of shapes, you know, like some graphical editor.